# How do i add a new line in html format in android?

Tags: android, html, text, button, android-layout

I have to add text to a button bolding the first line and unbolding the second but i cant figure out which new line character it is.

```
b.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + st + "<\b>" + "\n" + cursor.getString(1)));
```

ive also tried

```
b.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + st + "<\b>" + "<br/>" + cursor.getString(1)));
```

the second one works but both lines are bolded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Rather than using HTML to format your text (which is relatively slow) you could use Spans which give you much tighter control, and are more efficient. I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177) about the use of spans which may help you to get started.

Comment: ill look into that next time. thanks for the post! there is not much going on in this page so speed is not a big factor

Answer (score 22):

wrong end tag:

```
b.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + st + "</b>" + "<br/>" + cursor.getString(1)));
```