# How to have HTML New Line Feature in Android Text View?

Tags: android, html, string-formatting

I am using webservice in my android application. In my webservice result I get a HTML formatted String as result.

Assume this is my web service result:

**Books on Chennai**:\n

- *Madras Discovered, Tales of Old and New Madras, Madras* (1992) by S. Muthiah
  \n
- *Madras – its Past and its Present* (1995) by S. Muthiah
  \n
- *Madras – its Yesterdays and Todays and Tomorrows* by S. Muthiah
  \n
- *At Home in Madras* (1989) by S. Muthiah
  \n
- *The Spirit of Chepauk* (1998) by S. Muthiah
  \n
- *The Story Of Fort St. George* (1945) by Col. D.M. Reid
  \n
  **Fiction set in Chennai**
  \n
- *Kalyani’s Husband* by S. Y. Krishnaswamy
  \n
- ***Chasing Rainbows in Chennai*** (http://chasingrainbowsinchennai.blogspot.com/\">*Chasing Rainbows in Chennai*), (2003) by Colin Todhunter
  \n
- *In Old Madras* (1914) by Bithia Mary Crocker
  \n

I am using Html.fromHtml(String) to add this to my TextView. But I am not getting new line feature. I displays it as a paragraph.

Books on Chennai: Madras Discovered, Tales of Old and New Madras, Madras (1992) by S. Muthiah Madras – its Past and its Present (1995) by S. Muthiah Madras – its Yesterdays 
and Todays and Tomorrows by S. Muthiah At Home in Madras (1989) by S. Muthiah The Spirit of Chepauk (1998) by S. Muthiah The Story Of Fort St. George (1945) by Col. D.M. ReidFiction set in Chennai Kalyani’s Husband by S.Y. Krishnaswamy Chasing Rainbows in Chennai (Chasing Rainbows in Chennai), (2003) by Colin Todhunter In Old Madras (1914) by Bithia Mary Crocker

How can I present this data in an easily readable and understandable way?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Having this string as an example:

```
String sBooks = "Books on Chennai:\n ....";
```

Replace: `\n` with `<br>`:

```
sBooks = sBooks.replace("\n", "<br>");
```

Example using a `TextView`:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sBooks));
```

Comment: Funny, `<br/>` was the first thing I tried, and it didn't work. I guess fromHTML really doesn't like self-closing tags.

Comment: Another way is to use official documentation and put **&lt;**. E.g.: 

`<string name="message">Email is: &lt;b>%1$s&lt;/b>&lt;br/>Nickname is: &lt;b>%2$s&lt;/b></string>`

More info at: [Android String Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Comment: Everyone suggest to use <br />
It is not working.
But working with <br>

Answer (score 6):

Just replace `\n` with `<br/>` tag and then pass the whole string to `Html.fromHtml(String)`. By this it will be displayed in proper format.

Comment: Let, you are getting string as `String str`, then:
String newLine = "<br />"; 
`Html.fromHtml(str.replace("\n", newLine));`

Answer (score 3):

You should replace this `\n` with `<br>`. For more android `HTML` tags support go to [Android Support HTML Tags](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) or [daniel-codes.blogspot.in](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
b.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + your string+ "</b>" + "<br/>" + cursor.getString(1)));
```

Comment: Coy and Paste [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342042/how-do-i-add-a-new-line-in-html-format-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342042/how-do-i-add-a-new-line-in-html-format-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

If you are following kotlin

```
const val HTML_TAGS = " <br/> "
const val NEW_LINE = "\n"
      
val description = targetText?.replace(NEW_LINE, HTML_TAGS) ?: ""
text_view.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(description, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is instead of `TextView` use a `WebView` and

```
final String mimeType = "text/html";
    final String encoding = "UTF-8";
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", contentToShowString, mimeType,
            encoding, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with \r\n ?`

If this not works then you can try with :
  `\n` with escape sequence  : `\\\n`
I hope this will help you :)

Something like this

```
string = string.replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```