# Textview not getting displayed as desired from strings.xml

Tags: android, textview

I had to display some code in my textview with syntax highlighting. So i am testing if the syntax hhighligting works or not

I added some test code to my strings.xml and tried to display it in textview

Everything  works good but when the app is run the code is being displayed in 1 line
Like below
[image]

My code

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">syntaxtest</string>
<string name="javacode">
    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);

    }
    }</string>
```

**mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String code = getResources().getString(R.string.javacode);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);

    // code is a String with source code to highlight
     // myTextView is a TextView component
    PrettifyHighlighter highlighter = new PrettifyHighlighter();
    String highlighted = highlighter.highlight("java", code);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(highlighted));

}
}
```

Comment: you may have use "\n" explicitly to get to the next line

Answer (score 2):

Try escape sequences **'\t'** for tab and **'\n'** for new line.

```
<string name="javacode">
public class MainActivity extends Activity \n
{\n
@Override\n
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{\n
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);\n
setContentView(R.layout.main);\n
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);\n
}\n
}</string>
```

There are a number of other sequenes which may come handy for you, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1367339/681929)

Comment: Still facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved by adding "\n" at the end of each line.

```
<string name="app_name">syntaxtest</string>
<string name="javacode">
    public class MainActivity extends Activity\n
    {\n
    @Override\n
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)\n
    {\n
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);\n
    setContentView(R.layout.main);\n
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);\n
    }\n
    }</string>
```

**UPDATE :** 
`<tab>` for **space** and for **new line** use `<br>`

You are using `Html.fromHtml` so you need to add below code,

```
<string name="javacode">
<![CDATA[public class MainActivity extends Activity {<br></br>
@Override<br></br>
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)<br></br>
{<br></br>
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);<br></br>
setContentView(R.layout.main);<br></br>
TextView tv = (TextView)<br></br>
findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);<br></br>
}<br></br>
}]]></string>
```

Comment: Still facing the same problem

Comment: tried it bro,no changes even the end tags are being displayed

Comment: use CDATA or directly copy  my updated answer because i have tried this and it worked for me!!

Comment: i have copied your answer and tried, didnt work for me

Comment: try it without highlighter

Comment: it works without highlighter,yes but i need syntax highlighting to make the code more readable and presentable

Comment: try this, tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("![CDATA[" +highlighted+"]]")); i haven't tested

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n` where you need to go to next line in your string content.

`public class MainActivity extends Activity\n
{\n
@Override` 
like that.
Hope that helps

Comment: Still facing the same problem

Comment: Try using <br/>  instead of \n since you are using fromHtml... Maybe the 4th answer in this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840608/how-do-i-add-a-newline-to-a-textview-in-android

Comment: A similar problem is solved in this link. Maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670174/how-to-have-html-new-line-feature-in-android-text-view

Comment: tried even that bro still ni change, is there a probllem with my uighlighter class

Comment: Sorry... I am not sure about that

Comment: what to do this has become a pain for me

Answer (score 0):

your string:

```
<string name="javacode">
public class MainActivity extends Activity \n
{\n
\t@Override\n
\tprotected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
\t{\n
\t\tsuper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);\n
\t\tsetContentView(R.layout.main);\n
\t\tTextView tv = (TextView)\n
\t\tfindViewById(R.id.mainTextView);\n
\t}\n
}</string>
```

your MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String code = getResources().getString(R.string.javacode);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);       
        tv.setText(code);

    }
}
```

Comment: But i want syntax highlighting. If i do as you said the textview will be displayed without syntax highlighting