# Android TextView HTML text break at the end of line

Tags: android, html, textview, htmltext

In my text view, I am setting the HTML text:

```
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("THIS USEFUL INTERESTING HTML TEXT IS DISPLAYED IN ANDROID TEXT VIEW"));
```

The Text is displayed as below:
[image]

The long word at the end is breaking with a hyphen. I want the complete word to go into the next line instead. How can I achieve this? I need to use HTML text only. The text can be dynamic and has to scale across various display size and orientations, I cannot put newline char in the text.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use attribute [`android:ellipsize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:ellipsize) to prevent breaking up a word

Comment: No. I am adding HTML text. So, it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...it should work

```
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("THIS USEFUL" +"<br/>"+ "INTERESTING HTML TEXT IS DISPLAYED IN ANDROID TEXT VIEW"));
```

[How to have HTML New Line Feature in Android Text View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670174/how-to-have-html-new-line-feature-in-android-text-view) for more clarity

Comment: Not an option! When you have dynamic text, you don't know where to add a new line. Secondly, depending on display width across devices, this is going to break another part of the text.